# join more than vertexrdd[double] graphx scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I need to join more than 2 VertexRDD[Double].

I am trying it with the following code, but can't get it to work

```
val vertices=Array((1L, 11.0),(2L, 12.3),(3L,13.8)) 
val vRDD= sc.parallelize(vertices) 

val edges = Array(Edge(1L,2L,1800.0),Edge(2L,3L,800.0),Edge(3L,1L,1400.0)) 
val eRDD= sc.parallelize(edges)  

val vertices2=Array((1L, 1.0),(2L, 2.3),(3L,3.8)) 
val vRDD2= sc.parallelize(vertices2) 

val edges2 = Array(Edge(1L,2L,1800.0),Edge(2L,3L,800.0),Edge(3L,1L,1400.0)) 
val eRDD2= sc.parallelize(edges2)  

val vertices3=Array((1L, 21.0),(2L, 22.3),(3L,23.8)) 
val vRDD3= sc.parallelize(vertices3) 

val edges3 = Array(Edge(1L,2L,1800.0),Edge(2L,3L,800.0),Edge(3L,1L,1400.0)) 
val eRDD3= sc.parallelize(edges3) 

val g1 = Graph(vRDD,eRDD) 
val g2 = Graph(vRDD2,eRDD2) 
val g3 = Graph(vRDD3,eRDD3) 

//val vset3 = g1.vertices.join(g2.vertices)  
//val vset4 = vset3.join(g2.vertices)  
val vset3 = g1.vertices.leftZipJoin(g2.vertices) { (vid, a, b) => a+","+b }
```

output here:

```
1 11.0 1.0 21.0
2 12.3 2.3 22.3
3 13.8 3.8 23.8
```

Comment: Important for asking questions here on SO (or anywhere, really): When you say "can't get it to work", do you get errors? If so, what exactly do those errors say? Are they compile-time errors or runtime errors? Or, do you get other unexpected behavior? If so, what is it?

Comment: get other unexpected behavior 

1 11.0 (Some(1.0),Some(21.0))
2 12.0 (Some(2.3),Some(22.3))
3 13.0 (Some(3.8),Some(23.8))